# Why the debugging goes in file other than source?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

While debugging a client, deployed in Tomcat, the IntelliJ stops on the correct breakpoints, but is showing them not in the source file

```
InsuranceOfferItem.java
```

, but in the created class:

```
...\bsc.appl.IBS\webroot\WEB-INF\lib\geibs.jar!\bsc\gemini\custom\ge\ibs\InsuranceOfferItem.class
```

Of course, I cannot edit it and have to constantly switch to the source. That is very unconvenient. How can I make IntelliJ to use the source file for debugging?

Comment: Make sure the project dependencies do not contain the classes for the files you already have in sources.

Comment: Thank you. Not the classes, classes are ok. But along with classes I set the Sources dependency for a library.